# Rendering "Hand-drawn" Curves on Surfaces

Tags: bezier-curves, npr

As a mathematician (a topologist), I'm constantly creating diagrams similar to those shown below.
[image]

My broad goal is to make these diagrams look more professional by drawing (modeling?) them in Blender and then rendering them via NPR techniques.  The qualities that I'm looking for are:

1. The drawing is rendered with a "toon" or "hand-drawn" feel.
2. The pictures look "polished" and "crisp"

Examples of what I have in mind are renders which look like:
[image]
[image]

My problem is this: when I snap a bezier curve to the vertices of the mesh, the rendering does one of the following:

1. The curve "comes in and out" of the surface (i.e. the curve is puncturing the surface).
2. The curve is displaced from the surface and isn't flush.

My question is this: how do I draw an arbitrary smooth curve which is flush on a surface?

Comment: This question sounds too broad as it stands. What part of the workflow are you having difficulties with, modeling those shapes, drawing the lines, rendering NPR images? Do you already have the shapes you wist to draw over? Could you rephrase your question to focus on what part you are stuck?

Comment: You most certainly can do what you want with Blender, but I have to agree with @DuarteFarrajotaRamos.. so here's a [Blend File](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5177/)  that shows a one of many possible approaches. It might get you started,  and  trigger some more specific questions.